# Rectangular area has dimensions $240×360$ square metres, needed to be divided into equally square areas , what is the length of the square side?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Rectangular  area has dimensions $240×360$ square metres,  needed to be divided into equally square areas , what is the length of the square side ?

MY try

GCD $(240,360)=120$

Length of Square  side = divisors of $120= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 24, 30, 40, 60, 120}$

Is my solution right?

Comment: These are all possible side lengths; you get to pick any one or a combination.

Comment: @John Hughes  i list $1 , 2$  as square side

Comment: @Paul   the squares must have the same area , so they must have the same length side,  not combination  , aren't they ?

Comment: Fair enough.  But it doesn't say integer-length either.  You can also have any rational length $p/q$, as long as $p$ is one of the factors you list, and $q$ is any integer.

Comment: Did you mean *"what are the possible integer lengths of the square side?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the side of the square. Then the relationship between the sides of the rectangle is:
$$\frac{240}{x}+n=\frac{360}{x} \Rightarrow x=\frac{120}{n}.$$
If $n\in N$, then $x$ are the divisors of $120$. If $n\in R$, then $x$ can be infinitely many real numbers.